# Python Tkinter - for loop counter increment button error

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on creating a RPG status window for fun (like when you level up in a rpg and you add skill points to certain stats). I'm just trying to create the status window for now (showing the name of the player, the stats, and their class based on their stats, etc).

This is what I have so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

counter = IntVar()

def increase_stat(event=None):
    counter.set(counter.get() + 1)
def decrease_stat(event=None):
    counter.set(counter.get() - 1)

rnum = 0

for stat in ["Str","Int","Dex"]:
    Label(root, text=stat).grid(row=rnum, column=0)
    Label(root, textvariable=counter).grid(row=rnum+1, column=1)
    Button(root, text="+", command=increase_stat).grid(row=rnum+1, column=0)
    Button(root, text="-", command=decrease_stat).grid(row=rnum+1, column=2)
    rnum = rnum + 2

root.mainloop()
```

This is the result of this code so far:

[image: Result of this code]

The problem I'm having is that pressing the "+" or "-" button of any stat affects every other stat instead of just the stat I'm clicking. For example, clicking the "+" button under "Str" to add +1 to "Str" instead adds +1 to all three stats.

I'm just starting this so I'll be adding more than just those three stats (like displaying what class a character is based on the stats) so any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you have exactly one `IntVar` that you are increasing or decreasing, so how could it possibly work otherwise?  You need a separate var per stat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create one variable to record the increments and decrements for each label; you also must indicate which counter must be altered.

Maybe something like this?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

def increase_stat(event=None, counter=None):
    counter.set(counter.get() + 1)

def decrease_stat(event=None, counter=None):
    counter.set(counter.get() - 1)

counters = [tk.IntVar() for _ in range(3)]

rnum = 0
for idx, stat in enumerate(["Str", "Int", "Dex"]):
    tk.Label(root, text=stat).grid(row=rnum, column=0)
    tk.Label(root, textvariable=counters[idx]).grid(row=rnum+1, column=1)
    tk.Button(root, text="+", command=lambda counter=counters[idx]: increase_stat(counter=counter)).grid(row=rnum+1, column=0)
    tk.Button(root, text="-", command=lambda counter=counters[idx]: decrease_stat(counter=counter)).grid(row=rnum+1, column=2)
    rnum = rnum + 2

root.mainloop()
```